# Is it possible to write the server using grpc-java and call it from browser using grpc-web?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-web

We have our micro-services implemented in `grpc-java`, is it possible to call it from browser using `grpc-web`?

If yes any reference/documentation will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a grpc-web implementation in Java currently. You would need to use one of the normal grpc-web proxies (e.g., the [Envoy-based implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) or [Go implementation](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/go/grpcwebproxy)).